# Rewrite URL that matches a directory, has a specific HTTP query and does NOT have a specific HTTP query combination

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

I've come across plenty of questions dealing with redirecting based on HTTP queries and of course matching partial parts of URLs however *not both*.

My directory structure looks like the following:

- http://localhost/common_parent/.htaccess
- http://localhost/common_parent/demo/themes/
- http://localhost/common_parent/themes/?ajax=1

The rewrite that I have works fine except it blocks the directory in the second list item:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml$
RewriteRule ^[^/].*/themes(.+) themes$1 [L]
```

Unfortunately both `demo/themes/?ajax=1` and `themes/?ajax=1` are *both* requested with the `ajax` HTTP query. However only the `demo/themes/` is requested with a `foo` HTTP query.

- http://localhost/common_parent/demo/themes/?ajax=1&foo=bar
- http://localhost/common_parent/themes/?ajax=1

So in short how do I rewrite my `rewrite` to only apply if the `ajax` http query is present *and simultaneously* the `foo` http query is *not* present?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rewrite rule like this:

```sh
# when ajax=<whatever> query parameter is present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)ajax= [NC]
# when foo=<whatver> is not present
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(?:^|&)foo= [NC]
# when URI is not ending with .xml
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.xml$ [NC]
# rewrite handler
RewriteRule ^[^/].*/themes(.+) themes$1 [L]
```

Comment: Yeah, I had started messing with `%{QUERY_STRING}`, unfortunately that breaks a script accessing `themes/?ajax=`. I change the end to `(?:^|&)ajax(.+) [NC]` though it just hangs. Thoughts?

Comment: A rewrite rule can produce incorrect rewrite but it never hangs. Check in chrome dev tool what URL is being sent to web server and what response is coming back to browser.

Comment: I use Waterfox Classic by default and somehow Chrome handles the rewrite as desired though Waterfox does not. I also tried Firefox and there are no headers sent/received for the exact same URL request.

Comment: Never mind, it's an SSE request and I verified that it works. I changed the line to `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)ajax= [NC]`. Thank you, close enough!

Comment: Answer edited accordingly. Glad it worked out.